# Google Visualization Chart multiple Y axis one below each other

Tags: google-visualization

I have a chart with three data series. I want the two of them to be shown together which is fine.

For third one I want a different Y axis but not on the right side.
I want the third series to be shown bellow the other two like this one:
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/LogarithmicVsLinearAxes/jQuery/Light/

In my situation the logarithmic Yaxis of the example is for the first two data series and the linear Yaxis is for the third data series.

Is this possible? or I should go with two different charts?

I would prefer a solution with one graph so I can have a common crosshair line.

Comment: using google charts, would need two different charts...

Comment: @WhiteHat you are right . I had to do with 2 charts.